# Match a .htaccess content with regular expression in PHP

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, preg-match

I'm trying to `regex` match the couple of things from the content of `.htaccess` file.

Basically everything **in between** the comments
 `##bbc-startSOME_IP_HERE_AND_SOME_LABEL` and `##bbc-end`

The idea is to grab the rule between comments and replace it with empty string, if exists:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
##bbc-start-1Mail.RU_Bot
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} -1 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Mail.RU_Bot 
RewriteRule . - [F]
##bbc-end
##bbc-start66.249.78.150googlebot
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} 66.249.78.150 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} googlebot 
RewriteRule . - [F]
##bbc-end
##bbc-start157.55.33.50bingbot
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} 157.55.33.50 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} bingbot 
RewriteRule . - [F]
##bbc-end
</IfModule>
```

Used pattern is:

```
$regex_pattern = "/##bbc-start{$bot_banned_ip}{$bot_banned_mark}(.*?)##bbc-end/m";
```

...where `{$bot_banned_ip}` and `{$bot_banned_mark}` are  provided in runtime.

The above pattern was tested and works just fine on-line on http://www.rubular.com/r/bfoeQnah49

and on http://www.regexe.com/, but surprisingly fail to work in PHP environment, 5.3.18 with `preg_match()` or `preg_replace()`.

Do I miss something, is it the problem with my environment?

EDIT: The exact code is:

```
$file_contents = '<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    ##bbc-start-1Mail.RU_Bot
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} -1 [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Mail.RU_Bot 
    RewriteRule . - [F]
    ##bbc-end
    ##bbc-start66.249.78.150googlebot
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} 66.249.78.150 [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} googlebot 
    RewriteRule . - [F]
    ##bbc-end
    ##bbc-start157.55.33.50bingbot
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} 157.55.33.50 [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} bingbot 
    RewriteRule . - [F]
    ##bbc-end
    </IfModule>';
$regex_pattern = "/##bbc-start{$bot_banned_ip}{$bot_banned_mark}(.*?)##bbc-end/m";
$match = preg_match($regex_pattern, $file_contents);
//preg_match() returns 1 if the pattern matches given subject, 0 if it does not, or FALSE if an error occurred.    
if ($match===1) { /*DO SOME STUFF*/}
```

The strange thing is that `$match` is always 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need `s` switch for DOTALL and `preg_quote` function to escape your variables for possible regex symbols.

Try this regex:

```
$regex_pattern = "/##bbc-start" . preg_quote($bot_banned_ip, '/') . 
                 preg_quote($bot_banned_mark, '/') . "(.*?)##bbc-end/is";
```

Also do check your regex by doing:

```
var_dump ( $regex_pattern );
```

Comment: With preg_quote() the pattern is /##bbc\-start127\.0\.0\.1opera\(\.\*\?\)##bbc\-end/s

Comment: But I don't see any opera text in your .htaccess

Comment: Yes,it is a just example (opera or the IP are dynamic), the pattern with your modification is /##bbc-start127\.0\.0\.1opera(.*?)##bbc-end/is

Comment: Thank you, preg_quote() was the key player here, it must be used.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes indeed without `preg_quote` code can break anytime there is a `/` in the variables.

Answer (score 2):

[You want to use the `s` modifier, not `m`](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).  `s` is for DOTALL which allows `.` to match newlines.

Comment: It drives me crazy, loosed whole day, the exact code is in the question, nothing special, I have contents from .htaccess file and I search for the above cases

Comment: Are you sure that a newline (line end) is the same when you read in a file as when you enter a multiline source? Anyway, the 's' modifier _should_ treat a newline as a whitespace character and the data as one long string. And of course, $bot_banned_ip and $bot_banned_mark are defined, with reasonable values?

Comment: Yep, all values are reasonable, they come directly from .htaccess, I`m glad that you pointed me a direction for using the "s" modifier, the problem was that the values should be escaped with preg_quote(), as anubhava suggested.